# PHP auto complete in vs code doesn't work

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

My vscode doesnt auto complete the code or do the same thing the php intellisense do
but php intellisense don't have anymore on marketplace
i try other extensions but don't get success

Comment: "i try other extensions but don't get success" - Sorry but there's no way to provide an answer to that. Major extensions do certainly work or they wouldn't have thousands of downloads. We can't help you to troubleshoot an undisclosed extension with not diagnostics information. You won't do any better with some unknown extension that didn't show up in your search.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **PHP Intelephense**:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client